# Connect consumers jobs are getting deleted when restarting the cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am facing the below issue on changing some properties related to kafka and re-starting the cluster.

```
In kafka Consumer, there were 5 consumer jobs are running .
```

If we make some important property change , and on restarting cluster some/all the existing consumer jobs are not able to start.

```
Ideally all the consumer jobs should start ,
```

since it will take the meta-data info from the below System-topics .

```
config.storage.topic
offset.storage.topic
status.storage.topic
```

Comment: When you say restart the cluster do you mean just a shutdown and restart of just the kafka brokers or a reboot the entire Linux host it's running on? Are you storing the commit looking log in /tmp or in a docker container with ephemeral storage?

Comment: We make changes to kaka properties and re-start the cluster .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, a bit of background. Kafka stores all of its data in [topics](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_topics), but those topics (or rather the partitions that make up a topic) are append-only logs that would grow forever unless something is done. To prevent this, Kafka has the ability to clean up topics in two ways: retention and compaction. Topics configured to use ***retention*** will retain data for a configurable length of time: the broker is free to remove any log messages that are older than this. Topics configured to use [***compaction***](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) require every message have a key, and the broker will always retain the last known message for every distinct key. Compaction is extremely handy when each message (i.e., key/value pair) represents the last known state for the key; since consumers are reading the topic to get the last known state for each key, they will eventually get to that last state a bit faster if older states are removed.

Which cleanup policy a broker will use for a topic depends on several things. Every topic created implicitly or explicitly will use *retention* by default, though you can change a couple of ways:

- change the globally `log.cleanup.policy` broker setting, affecting only topics created after that point; or
- specify the `cleanup.policy` topic-specific setting when you [create or modify a topic](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_add_topic)

Now, Kafka Connect uses several *internal topics* to store connector configurations, offsets, and status information. These internal topics **must** be [*compacted* topics](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) so that (at least) the last configuration, offset, and status for each connector are always available. Since Kafka Connect never uses older configurations, offsets, and status, it's actually a good thing for the broker to remove them from the internal topics.

Before Kafka 0.11.0.0, the [recommended process](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.1/connect/userguide.html#prerequisites) is to manually create these internal topics using the correct topic-specific settings. You could rely upon the broker to auto-create them, but that is problematic for several reasons, not the least of which is that the three internal topics should have different numbers of partitions.

If these internal topics are not *compacted*, the configurations, offsets, and status info will be cleaned up and removed after the retention period has elapsed. By default this retention period is 24 hours! That means that if you restart Kafka Connect more than 24 hours after deploying / updating a connector configuration, that connector's configuration may have been purged and it will appear as if the connector configuration never existed.

So, if you didn't create these internal topics correctly, simply use the [topic admin tool](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_modify_topic) to update the topic's settings as [described in the documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.1/connect/userguide.html#prerequisites).

BTW, not properly creating these internal topics is a very common problem, so much so that Kafka Connect 0.11.0.0 will be able to automatically create these *internal* topics using the correct settings without relying upon broker auto-creation of topics.

In 0.11.0 you will still have to rely upon manual creation or broker auto-creation for topics that *source connectors write to*. This is not ideal, and so there's a [proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-154+Add+Kafka+Connect+configuration+properties+for+creating+internal+topics) to change Kafka Connect to automatically create the topics for the source connectors while giving the source connectors control over the settings. Hopefully that improvement makes it into 0.11.1.0 so that Kafka Connect is even easier to use.

Comment: Thank you Randall .. for your updates. I have one doubt.. what are u mean to say by topics are not compacted . Do we need to do any config changes ..

Comment: @SoumyajitChatterjee, I've updated my answer to include more detail and explanation of what compacted topics are. Confluent's documentation has even more detail about how to set up the topics correctly.