# Kafka Connect: Connectors Disappear when Worker shutsdown

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I run a Kafka Connect Distributed worker:

```
~ /usr/bin/connect-distributed /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties
```

I configure my Kafka Connect connectors:

```
~ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "@my_s3_sink_1.json" localhost:8083/connectors/my-s3-sink-1/config | jq '.'
```

Everything works great. I can query connector status, task status, all my topic data is being written to S3 like I expect. Everything is working perfectly. It runs for literally weeks without problems. All data is sinked to S3 perfectly.

Then my Kafka Connect Distributed worker gets killed. So I restart it on the exact same worker server.

```
~ /usr/bin/connect-distributed /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties
```

All my Kafka Connect connectors are gone:

```
~ curl localhost:8083/connectors
[]
```

Why!?!?!? It's my understanding that the Kafka Connect worker is stateless. All connector configuration and state is stored within Kafka. I should be able to stop and restart the worker process without problems. That didn't work. My connectors seem to be gone and the state seems to be gone.

I can see the three Kafka Connect topics:

```
~ /usr/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list

(other topics)
connect-configs
connect-offsets
connect-statuses
```

If I try to view these topics, they seem to be empty:

```
~ sudo /usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic connect-configs --from-beginning

(nothing)

~ sudo /usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic connect-offsets --from-beginning

(nothing)
```

This is a problem! I need this Connect system to be able to handle a restarted worker process.

I still have the JSON configuration file. I can easily reload the configuration for the connector, but then it will restart at offset 0. I want it to simply resume and not lose state.

FYI, I am running with Confluent Platform v3.2.1 on a three server Debian Jessie (8) cluster.

Comment: The short answer is that Kafka Connect's internal topics are not be created correctly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699226/connect-consumers-jobs-are-getting-deleted-when-restarting-the-cluster) for details.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a major problem. Why would normal users of Kafka think that the defaults are basically wrong and think to manually create these internal topics without any explicit guidance or warning to do so? I am glad that seems to be fixed in Kafka 0.11, but the new Confluent Platform based on that isn't even available for use yet.

Comment: Are there any other gotchas I should know about?

Comment: Kafka supports a variety of use cases, and they all have different needs and topic settings. Apache Kafka 0.11 does fix this for internal topics (and Confluent Platform 3.3 will be available soon). But even prior to Confluent 3.3, their documentation does talk about [needing to create these topics manually](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#planning-for-installation) rather than relying upon topic auto-creation. Don't rely upon topic auto-creation of source connector topics, either.

Comment: Randall Hauch, Thank you so much! What is a "source connector topic"? Is that one of `connect-configs`, `connect-offsets`, `connect-statuses` or something else entirely? I searched the docs for that term and didn't find any matches.

Comment: No, by "source connector topic" I'm referring to the topics that a source connector writes to. Quite a few source connectors dynamically determine the topics they write to, based upon the content in the source. For example, Confluent's JDBC connector writes to a topic per table (or query).